# Erro ao tentar importar arquivo .bak do Sql Server no Linux

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sou muito iniciante no SQL Server e estou tentando importar um arquivo .bak de um backup que veio de outro servidor (Windows) no Linux (Linux mint 19)

O comando que utilizei no terminal foi [esse](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-backup-and-restore-database?view=sql-server-2017):

```
sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -Q "RESTORE DATABASE [demodb] FROM DISK = N'/home/usuario/html/projeto_sql/backup.bak' WITH FILE = 1, NOUNLOAD, REPLACE, STATS = 5"
```

Os erros são:

```
Msg 5133, Level 16, State 1, Server homepc, Line 1
Directory lookup for the file "E:\Banco Dados\Banco1.mdf" failed with the operating system error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.).

Msg 3156, Level 16, State 3, Server homepc, Line 1
File 'Banco1' cannot be restored to 'E:\Banco Dados\Banco1.mdf'. Use WITH MOVE to identify a valid location for the file.

Msg 5133, Level 16, State 1, Server homepc, Line 1
Directory lookup for the file "E:\Banco Dados\Banco1_log.ldf" failed with the operating system error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.).

Msg 3156, Level 16, State 3, Server homepc, Line 1
File 'Banco1_log' cannot be restored to 'E:\Banco Dados\Banco1_log.ldf'. Use WITH MOVE to identify a valid location for the file.

Msg 3119, Level 16, State 1, Server homepc, Line 1
Problems were identified while planning for the RESTORE statement. Previous messages provide details.

Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Server homepc, Line 1
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

**OBS:**

1. Minha versão do SQL SERVER rodando é a

   Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU13) (KB4466404) - 14.0.3048.4 (X64) 
       Nov 30 2018 12:57:58 
       Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
       Developer Edition (64-bit) on Linux (Linux Mint 19.1)
2. Não sei em qual versão do SQL Server/ ou como o arquivo .bak foi criado, isso importa?
3. Venho do MySQL, existe algum tipo de arquivo .sql que pode ser criado ou o backup do SQL Server precisa de várias arquivos e não somente o .bak?

Comment: A instalação do SQL Server 2017 para Linux foi através de docker?

Comment: Não, instalei seguindo o manual no site da microsoft mesmo

Answer (score 1):

O SQL Server 2017 para Linux é compatível com o Ubuntu 16.04; não sei se ele é estável no Linux Mint 19.1, que é derivado do Ubuntu 18.04. No artigo [Installing SQL Server 2017 for Linux on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_server_team/installing-sql-server-2017-for-linux-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts/) consta como instalar o SQL Server 2017 para Linux no Ubuntu 18.04.

A opção REPLACE somente é necessária quando já existe o banco de dados e se quer substituir pelo conteúdo do backup. Como o banco de dados foi criado em outro ambiente operacional, retire o `REPLACE` e utilize `WITH MOVE`. As instruções completas de como restaurar o backup na distribuição GNU/linux estão em [Migrate a SQL Server database from Windows to Linux using backup and restore](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-migrate-restore-database?#restore-your-database-on-linux).

Exemplo:

```
RESTORE DATABASE Banco1 
   FROM DISK = '/home/usuario/html/projeto_sql/backup.bak'
   WITH MOVE 'Banco1' TO '/home/usuario/html/projeto_sql/Banco1.mdf',
        MOVE 'Banco1_Log' TO '/home/usuario/html/projeto_sql/Banco1_Log.ldf'
GO
```

Sugiro que instale o Azure Data Studio para manipular o SQL Server diretamente no ambiente GNU/Linux, em interface gráfica. Obtenha-o no [Porto SQL](https://portosql.wordpress.com/), menu `SQL Server`, item `download`.